# Subtraction of values depending on time SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, case

For each `EVENT_TYPE` that is repeated more than once

[image]

I need a SQL statement that returns the `event_type` and the subtraction of the last value registered for this `event_type` and the second value. I appreciate your help

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: This is what i did: 
select event_type , sum(case events.value having count(*) - events.value having count(*)=2)  As `value` from events where event_type having count(*)>1;

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala this is a small project I'm trying to build skills on it

Comment: @YoussefAzougagh What DBMS is this for?  The answer will be different depending on what you're using.

Comment: @Siyual PostgreSQL

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) (or [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) if you prefer) to get the next record in the series, and calculate the difference only when there is another record and only taking the latest `Time` per `Event_Type`:

```
With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Event_Type Order By Time Desc) As Row_Number,
            Lead(Value) Over (Partition By Event_Type Order By Time Desc) As Prev
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Event_Type, Value - Prev As Value
From    Cte
Where   Prev Is Not Null
And     Row_Number = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select e.event_type,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then value when seqnum = 2 then - value end) as diff
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e.event_type order by e.time desc) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
group by e.event_type
having count(*) >= 2;
```